# Skip every 4 and wrap every 3 child

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have parent with divs like this:

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
</div>
```

I need to wrap every 3 elements and skip every 4, like this:

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying doing like this, but it's only wrap each 3 elements

```
var divs = $(".products .product");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i +=3) { divs.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll("<div class='wrap'>
    </div>");
}
```

Comment: `i +=4` would result in what you want

Comment: [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8495687/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the correct `end` in the slice. Also once `wrapped`
you need to update `i` with correct value

```js
var divs = $(".products .product");
let i = 0;

while (i < divs.length) {
  divs.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll("<div class='wrap'> </div>");
  i = i + 4

}
```

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="products">
  <div class="product">1</div>
  <div class="product">2</div>
  <div class="product">3</div>
  <div class="product">4</div>
  <div class="product">5</div>
  <div class="product">6</div>
  <div class="product">7</div>
  <div class="product">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can i skip first instead?

Comment: only first one ? start i from 1